# How to write an iterated function in Pari/GP

Tags: pari-gp

I am absolutely new to pari/gp. After watching a few videos on YouTube and looking through some online pdf tutorial files, 5 hours later I am still at a loss on how to write the iterated function below.  I was using Excel but needed something that can handle very large numbers and was introduced to pari. The Excel formula is very simple and goes like this for b = 7 and c = 9/7: 
(1) with numbers 1 to 10^5 in Column A; 
(2) type the formula =IF(MOD(A1,7)=0,A1/7,CEILING(A1*9/7,1)) in B1; and 
(3) drag B1 down to A100000 then drag the entire column horizontally as far as needed.

**Iterated Function**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should retag this from `[pari]` to `[pari-gp]`, which is the correct tag for Pari/GP questions (can't edit because edit queue is full)

Comment: @astroide Thanks. Will do.

Comment: I posted a solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4345437/1714 (needs Pari/GP version  \ge 2.13.0 )